# Sending values from one page to multiple pages JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

In **1.jsp** I have this input boxes

```
<input type="hidden" id="muncId" name="muncId"/>
<input type="hidden" id="muncDesc" name="muncDesc"/>
```

I want to send the values in **2.jsp, 3.jsp, 4.jsp etc.**

The form submit is for one page only. How should I do that in multiple pages?

Comment: do you have any servlet in between?

Comment: As far as I understand your question you want to submit the form in your 1.jsp page to multiple pages with one click, right?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia, none.

Answer (score 0):

the other alterante for hidden form field is to use session.Kepp the values in session
In 1.jsp keep the values in session like this

```
session.setAttribute("value","hi");
```

now in other pages 2.jsp,3.jsp,4.jsp retrive the values from session like this

```
session.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Thanks, can you guide me to that?

Comment: @Arem I gave an example,try this way.If you find any problem then you can ask me

Comment: Be careful with placing values in the session. They will stay there as long as the session lives or you programatically remove them. If you just need these parameters for one (or multiple parallel) request (as it looks like in your case) I would prefer to post them with the request.

Answer (score -1):

In your 1.jsp page include one form for each target page containing the same hidden fields.
Add a little JavaScript to your submit button to submit all forms on click.

Comment: Does it redirect you to all targeted pages?

Comment: You should be able to open the results of each form in a new browser tab/window by defining a target="_blank" parameter in each of the forms.